# How to remove bottom color in Button primary of ant design?

Tags: button, components, antd

How to remove this bottom border of primary Button component of ant design ?

[image]

When i added `"colorBgContainer": "#161616"` in design token theme, this border bottom appear and i dont wanna this.
How can i remove it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the `button box-shadow` style. You have some ways of removing it:

You can set `primaryShadow` prop on `Button` token config:

OBS: You can find every prop you can change on every component token styles [here](https://ant.design/theme-editor)

```
<ConfigProvider
  theme={{
    token: {
      colorBgContainer: "#161616",
      ... other props, 
     
      Button: {
        primaryShadow: "none"
      }
    }
  }}
>
  .....

</ConfigProvider>
```

Or set `boxShadow` prop on Button `style` prop:

```
<Button 
  type="primary"
  style={{
    boxShadow: 'none'
  }}
>
  Submit
</Button>
```

You can also use `css` files in two ways:

Overwrite every Button css class:

```
.ant-btn {
  // don't forget to add !important at end 
  // so antd will not overwrite your styles
  box-shadow: none !important;
}
```

Or overwrite only desired Button style by assigning a custom class to desired Button:

```
<Button 
  type="primary"
  className={'customStyledButton'}
>
  Submit
</Button>

// css
.customStyledButton {
  box-shadow: none !important;
}
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: nice, it works! 
thanks..

Comment: @rusliAbdulgani You're wellcome. Also don't forget to accept my anser as your question sollution ;)